# OGE no value for load_avg

Tags: linux, centos, gridengine

There is a problem with my OGE configuration. The load_avg for the nodes does not get set (remains at -NA-). Because of this and because of the np_load_avg threshold on the queue no jobs are being run.

```
[ce@node1 ce]$ qhost -F -l h=node2
HOSTNAME                ARCH         NCPU  LOAD  MEMTOT  MEMUSE  SWAPTO  SWAPUS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
node2                   -               -     -       -       -       -       -
```

No errors pop up in default/spool/localhost/messages nor in qmaster/messages. The queue scheduling message is 'no value for complex attribute np_load_avg'.

I do not see any indications as to what could be going wrong, the following works on the execution node:

- gethostname
- gethostbyname master
- qstat -f
- loadcheck

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my /etc/hosts file, I had:

```
127.0.0.1 node2
```

this had to become:

```
10.0.0.2    node2
```

Finally giving me

```
[ce@node1 ce]$ qhost -F -l h=node2
HOSTNAME                ARCH         NCPU  LOAD  MEMTOT  MEMUSE  SWAPTO  SWAPUS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
node2                   linux-x64       8  0.00   31.3G  308.8M   11.9G     0.0
```

and

```
[ce@node2 ce]# utilbin/linux-x64/gethostname 
Hostname: node2
Aliases:  
Host Address(es): 10.0.0.2
```